# The function '_neverSatisfied' isn't used. dart(unused_element)

Tags: dart, flutter

Got the below problem, please help me in solving the issue from the image below

**CODE SAMPLE**

[image]

Comment: The message is pretty self explanatory. That method isn't being used. It's not called from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, @JordanDavies. But this is the example seen from the widgets example from this link, https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html.  So once can you look into that .

Comment: Ok, but to run the code in the method you need to call the method. Do you have `_neverSatisfied(context)` in your code anywhere? Because the message is saying that you don't.

Comment: Yeah I need to call that method, and don't have anywhere "_neverSatisfied(context)". Just declaring the function is seen in that code.@JordanDavies